# Django:How to access logged in user's data in widget on other sites?

Tags: django, authentication

I have a webapp where a user can carry out a particular action only when he's logged in.I've developed a widget which other users can put on their sites.I used pinax as a foundation of the webapp.But on my widget I'm not getting the currently logged in user even when the user is logged in on my website.

Comment: How is the widget included? An iframe?

Comment: Nope,I use ajax to inject a div into the page.

Comment: That's you problem. The session cookie will only be set for your domain, and won't be passed to a 3rd-party domain. This is by design and ideal. Otherwise, any site could hijack any other site's authentication details. You'll have to figure out another way, to pass the info. If it's just a GET, you can probably just include the user_id and not worry too much, but if any changes will be made, you'll need something more robust. Personally, I'd recommend just using an iframe. This is how Facebook, Twitter, etc. do it -- for good reason.